# Test fails asp.net boilerplate. Abp.AbpException : There is no permission with name: Pages.Users

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

When I run web.mvc project (of asp.net boilerplate template) the following exception is throwed:

```
Abp.AbpException: There is no permission with name: Pages.Tenants.
```

I updated database. How to fix these problems? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can check AuthorizationProvider of your solution, in `SetPermissions` method, Permissions are added to the context.